# Cannot find element in Window object in Chrome, but works in IE

Tags: javascript

I have the following javascript for a multiselect dropdown list with checkboxes which works just fine in IE:

```
function checkAll(textId, checkId, hiddenId) {
var checkBox1 = document.getElementById(checkId);
var textElement = document.getElementById(textId);
var hiddenElement = document.getElementById(hiddenId);
    if (checkBox1.checked) {
        for (var item in window[textId]) {
            if (typeof window[textId][item] != "function") {
                var checkBox = document.getElementById(item);
                if (window[textId][item].text != "Not Supported")
                try
                {
                    checkBox.checked = true;
                    }
                    catch (exception)
                    {
                    }
                if (window[textId][item].text != "Select/De-select All" && window[textId][item].text != "Not Supported")
                    textElement.value += window[textId][item].text + ", ";
                    hiddenElement.value += window[textId][item].value + "|";                   
            }
        }
        }
     else if (!checkBox1.checked) {
            for (var item in window[textId]) {
                if (typeof window[textId][item] != "function") {
                    var checkBox = document.getElementById(item);
                    checkBox.checked = false;
                    textElement.value = "";
                    hiddenElement.value = 0;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

However, in Chrome it does not work. The problem is that this line

```
for (var item in window[textId])
```

assigns to the var item the actual checkbox id

```
ctl00_MainContent_TabContainer1_TabPanel1_Multiselect1_ctl01
```

in IE. However, in Chrome, this assigns to item something called "webkitEntries," which is not what I am looking for. btw textID here is the ID of the parent control

```
ctl00_MainContent_TabContainer1_TabPanel1_Multiselect1_TextControl
```

Does anyone know how to get the checkbox id for each in Chrome? Thanks and apologies for any lack of clarity -- I`m pretty new to js

Comment: You may add a .hasownproperty() check inside the loop, google for examples

Comment: I`m not sure how that would help since I need the actual element, not whether or not Chrome can find it by the given ID (I know it cannot). I`m not sure how a boolean value would help me here

Comment: Looping over items in javascript without 'filtering' may also return 'unwanted' items/properties that are inherited from their prototype, some of these items may be specific to chrome/WebKit. Usually you'll filter out these inherited properties by checking if a property is 'inherited' or not using hasownproperty(). An example can be found here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty

Comment: that sounds great but I couldn`t get it to work. When I register each checkbox in the list I added a property "someproperty" like this:    window[textId][checkId] = { "text": checkText, "value": checkValue, "someproperty" : 0 };. However, when I check like this:  for (var item in window[textId]) {
                alert("does item have own property:" + item + " " + item.hasOwnProperty("someproperty"));
                if (item.hasOwnProperty("someproperty")) {.... then it returns false for my checkboxes. I feel like there is something simple I can do to fix it but I don`t know what